# ElasticSearch - How use multi_match with nested objects out "should" context?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, nosql

I have a document with several rootless fields and some "searchable" fields inside an array of (nested) objects.
I have read in several places that do a search using the "should" as for example:

```
{
  "should": [
     {
        "nested": {
            "path": "Variants",
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "any_thing",
                    "fields": ["Variants.value"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "any_thing",
            "fields": ["reference", "another_field"]
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I can not use "should" because it was not made to do the "OR_CONDITION" and when there are "FILTER / MUST" in the query the "should" interfere in the score.

I also saw that in document 6.0 there is no longer the "include_in_root" for me to reference, such as:

```
"multi_match" : {
  "query" : "any_thing",
  "fields" : [ "reference", "Variants.value" ] 
}
```

Mapping :

```
        {
           "reference": {
                "type": "text"
           },
           "Variants": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "value": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "phonetic"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My question is: How to perform an elastic search by combining fields within a "nested" and "root" fields remembering that I can not use "should" and putting everything inside the "must" most of the time would not bring anything already which would force an AND (combine in the two fields that not for me would be an invalid query because I need a similar behavior to the OR)

Note: If there is any other solution outside of MULTI_MATCH, I accept it as a valid answer as well. (I'm using elastic 6.0)

Comment: Not sure what you trying to get. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596440/elastic-search-bool-query-in-nested-properties/47616576#47616576) could help.

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/multi-match-best-fields-with-complex-queries-no-dis-max/110121