# Elastic Search: Bool Query in nested properties

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets assume I have data structured like this:

```
 { "id": "120400871755634330808993320",
                    "name": "Metaalschroef binnenzeskant, DIN 912 RVS A4-80",
                    "description": "m16x70 cilinderschroef bzk a4-80 din912 klasse 80",
                    "fullDescription": "Metaalschroef met een binnenzeskant cilinderkop",
                    "synonyms": [],
                    "properties": [
                        {
                            "name": "draad",
                            "value": "16",
                            "sort": 99
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "lengte",
                            "value": "70",
                            "sort": 99
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "materiaal",
                            "value": "roestvaststaal",
                            "sort": 99
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "kwaliteit (materiaal)",
                            "value": "A4",
                            "sort": 99
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "DIN",
                            "value": "912",
                            "sort": 99
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AISI",
                            "value": "316",
                            "sort": 99
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "draadsoort",
                            "value": "metrisch",
                            "sort": 99
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Merk",
                            "value": "Elcee Holland",
                            "sort": 1
                        }
                    ]
}
```

How do I write a boolean query where I select all documents that have a property with name "draad" and value "16" and a property with name "lengte" and value "70".

Right now I have this but it returns 0 results:

```
"query" : {
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "properties",
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [{
                        "bool" : {
                            "must" : [{
                                    "term" : {
                                        "properties.name" : "Merk"
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    "term" : {
                                        "properties.value" : "Facom"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "bool" : {
                            "must" : [{
                                    "term" : {
                                        "properties.name" : "materiaal"
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    "term" : {
                                        "properties.value" : "kunststof"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Replacing the highest level "must" with "should" returns too many results, which makes sense as it translates to an "or".

Comment: Can you add your mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that is working very well!

My property object now looks like this:

```
                    {
                        "name": "breedte(mm)",
                        "value": "1000",
                        "unit": "mm",
                        "sort": 99,
                        "nameSlug": "breedte-mm",
                        "slug": "breedte-mm-1000"
                    },
```

I added a slug (containing a normalized string for key + value) and a nameslug which is a normalized string for the name.

My index is mapped like this:

```
                "properties": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "include_in_parent": true,
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "nameSlug": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "slug": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "sort": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "unit": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "index": false
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The "include_in_parent" is important here. It allows me to do the query below:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "properties.slug": [
              "merk-orbis",
              "merk-bahco"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "properties.slug": [
              "materiaal-staal",
              "materiaal-kunststof"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

This queries searches for all documents where "merk" is "Orbis" or "Bahco" and where "materiaal" is "staal" or "kunststof".

My aggregations look like this:

```
"merk_query": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "properties.slug": [
                      "materiaal-staal",
                      "materiaal-kunststof"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "merk_facets": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "properties"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "merk_only": {
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "properties.nameSlug": {
                        "value": "merk"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "facets": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "properties.name",
                        "size": 1
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "facetvalues": {
                          "terms": {
                            "field": "properties.value",
                            "size": 10
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

I run filteraggregate which filters all documents that match a facet (but not the current one I am bulding).

The result of this aggragate is something like this:

```
"merk_query": {
                "doc_count": 7686,
                "merk_facets": {
                    "doc_count": 68658,
                    "merk_only": {
                        "doc_count": 7659,
                        "facets": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "Merk",
                                    "doc_count": 7659,
                                    "facetvalues": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 10,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 438,
                                        "buckets": [
                                        {
                                            "key": "Orbis",
                                            "doc_count": 6295
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": "DX",
                                            "doc_count": 344
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": "AXA",
                                            "doc_count": 176
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": "Talen Tools",
                                            "doc_count": 127
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": "Nemef",
                                            "doc_count": 73
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": "bonfix",
                                            "doc_count": 67
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": "Bahco",
                                            "doc_count": 64
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": "Henderson",
                                            "doc_count": 27
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": "Maasland Groep",
                                            "doc_count": 25
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": "SYSTEC",
                                            "doc_count": 23
                                        }
                                    ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

And this is the end result in the browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using `must`, the engine is trying to search for nested documents with `name:Merk` and `value:Facom`. But also with `name:materiaal` and `value:kunststof` - which is impossible to happen in the same nested document at once.

When using `should` as you mentioned, it translate to `or` - which is indeed possible.

Problem is, you also getting the entire parent document with all it's nested documents.

In my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971933/extract-record-from-multiple-arrays-based-on-a-filter/47000112#47000112) I'm showing the steps to create an index with `nested` documents (you should mark the field `properties` as nested type`).

After complete those steps, you'll be able to get results with the following query:

```
{
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "description"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "properties",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "properties.name": "Merk"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "properties.value": "Facom"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "properties.name": "materiaal"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "properties.value": "kunststof"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits":{
              "size": 10
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Eli, I've tried your suggestion but I'm still getting the results as if it is an OR query.

Comment: I guess I missed your point. Can you add an example for the result you are expecting to get? (according to your data above)

Comment: I've solved it by adding a new property in the properties array which is a composite of both name and value. 
Eg: materiaal-kunstof. This allows me to search with a query like this:

                       {
                          "term": {
                            "properties.slug": "materiaal-kunststof"
                          }
                        }